# Manhwa with time travel and poisoned chocolates

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

I remember the story but not the title. The female lead and male lead were married. The female character was blond and the man had black/blue hair.

One day the woman gave the man some foreign chocolates and after that the man died. A court was held but nevertheless she was punished.

Later she found out her mom planned all of this when she went back in time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may be ***[Crazy Princess Renia](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/crazy-princess-renia)***.

From Anime-Planet:

> Renia is the princess of the Fontiano Empire. Her happy days were now shattered, after she married Duke Clovis Zenov. “I’m innocent, I swear to god I never intended to kill my beloved husband!” Reality was like hell, nothing changed even if she screamed in pain. Now all that’s left for her is the blessing of death... To forget everything and find a place to rest in the arms of God, she stabbed the knife in the back of her head. However, God ignored and did not grant her last wish. On her 18th birthday, the happiest day of her life. Blood-stained memories returned.

At the beginning of the story, Renia Zenov is sentenced to death for the murder of her husband, Clovis. Although she did hand him the box of poisoned chocolates that killed him, they were delivered to the house by someone else, and she had no idea they were poisoned. While awaiting execution in a prison cell, she discovers it was her mother who sent the chocolates. She then commits suicide and wakes up in the past, on her 18th birthday.

[image] [image]

Comment: Thank you. This is the one I was looking for.